# best way to put some variable(s) in Laravel->Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, undefined, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel, and I if want, for example, have available a variable in all the views by default, is there a better way than passing that variable every time w/

```
return View::make('views_x.some_view')->with('client_to_show', $client_to_show);
```

? Or better than storing them in Session and then accessing them in the view?
I tried putting the variable in layout master:

```
//layout.master.blade.php on top
<?php 
  $str_sel_names        = 'one_value';
?>
<!-- starts template -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

but this one is only accesible inside the template-layout.. not the subview...

`@extends('layouts.master')`

```
@section('content')
...
{{$str_sel_names}}
```

I get: [ErrorException
Undefined variable: str_sel_names (View: C:\Work\lara_street\laravel\app\views\core\dashboard.blade.php)]

Ideas? Better ways to do this?

Comment: Put them in an array, or as properties of a StdClass object and pass that to Blade

Comment: yea.. but in that case i understand i'd have to pass it explicitly to the view.. over and over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use View Composers:

```
View::composer(['store.index', 'products.*'], function($view)
{
    $view->with('client_to_show', $client_to_show);
});
```

You can put that in your routes file, filters file or, like, me, create a `app/composers.php` and load by adding

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

To your `app/start/global.php` file.

View Share is another option:

```
View::share('client_to_show', $client_to_show);
```

Comment: where should i put this view::share call?

Comment: Depends on how you get the infor for your $client_to_show. But you can add to your controller __construct(), but if this is something global, you also can use a file like `app/composers.php`, as I've said in the last answer edit.